# One WAR with multiple web services on multiple ports in GlassFish

Tags: glassfish-4

I have a jax-rs web application running in GlassFish 4 (Open Source Edition). The single application has both public web services and admin web services. I would like the public services to run on a different port than the admin services. For example:

```
http://my.domain:8080/app/public/*
http://my.domain:8081/app/admin/*
```

I've seen answers that suggest the ability to bind an entire WAR to a particular port or network listener. But how do you bind web services within a WAR to particular ports?